# Oracle SQL Developer won't connect to local database, OCI library won't load

Tags: java, database, oracle, ide, oracle-sqldeveloper

I opened Oracle SQL Developer after using it for a while a few days ago and then I run into this mysterious and infuriating issue where I cannot connect to my locally installed database. First I got a report of the JDBC driver being outdated when testing the connection, so I replaced it with the updated version and then tried again, but then got a different error saying the OCI library won't load. The path to my Oracle Databse Express Edition 18 installation that works as `ORACLE_HOME` is `C:\app\nicho\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE`. I don't understand why the OCI library won't load, as the oci.dll and associated oci files are all in the directory the error message specifies: `C:\app\nicho\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin`. I tried using the Instant Client option in the Tools->Preferences->Database->Advanced section by downloading the Oracle Instant Client and changing the path, but I got the same OCI library load failed message. This problem is very significant because I need to use this software for my college project and cannot do my work. I don't understand why this error is happening.

```
Testing the Oracle Home located at C:\app\nicho\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
  Driver version: 21.1.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... Failed:
  Error loading the native OCI library
  The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system propertyjava.library.path contains the entries from the environment variable PATH. Check it to verify that
  the expected native library directory C:\app\nicho\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin is present and precedes any other client installations.
  java.library.path = C:\Users\nicho\OneDrive\Documents\IS 410\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\app\nicho\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin;C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
```

As you can see, the expected native library directory is in the path, but the OCI driver will still not load. My database and installation were working fine before today. Please help. :(

Comment: What version of sqldev? Are you trying a thick connection? Disable OCI and you be able to connect.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am using SQL Developer 20.4.1.407.0006 and I have tried unchecking and checking "Use Oracle Client" in Tools->Preferences->Database->Advanced, changing the filepath for Oracle Home (my XE installation is in the path shown above, but that doesn't seem to work). Checking "Use OCI/Thick Driver" doesn't seem to matter either. Whenever I click connect in the main IDE window, I get  "i/o error network adapter could not establish connection. vendor code 17002." I'm really not sure why because it was working fine before. Maybe I don't need OCI and the problem is something else.

Comment: That error indicates something else is going on...you could also try 20.4.0 which doesn't require 21c client for thick connections

Comment: If you're switching to JDBC-thin then you need a TCP listener on your XE database